# How to refer to routes for a rspec-capybara feature test?

Tags: rspec, capybara

My test has

```
 scenario 'with all required fields entered' do
   fill_out_form zip.zip_code
   click_button(page_object.eqv_continue_button)
   expect(page).to have_css(page_object.css_vehicle1_ownership)
   expect(current_path).to eq(landings_path)
 end
```

but I get

```
/Users/pengo/eq/lynx/spec/features/full_flows/3_step_minimal_foundation_spec.rb:23:
in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `landings_path' for #<Class:0x007fe320eba310> (NameError)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using rspec-rails and your test is tagged  with :type => :feature
then the url helpers should be included automatically.  If not you can try including them via your RSpec configuration

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  ...
end
```